# Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll not found after installing Enterprise Lib 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enterprise-library

I have recently installed Enterprise library 5.0 but I am unable to find "Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll". I am working on  CAL[Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) where I will need this dll as reference.

Can anybody answer this?

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is breaking change in EntLib 5. The library help file mentioned about this which says that code for "Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll" is included in Unity assembly hence no need of separate reference.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has a similar issue, I am responsible for a project that uses the NetTiers templates to generate data/service layers. The templates were configured to use EntLib 4.1 and I updated them to use EntLib 5. For the most part this was successful but NetTiers defines a class *EntityLocator* that is derived from *ObjectBuilder2.Locator*. Unfortunately the *Locator* class was removed from ObjectBuilder in the EntLib 5 release of Unity.

To address this, and due to *Locator* being referenced in the NetTiers templates, the easiest solution for me was to download the [Unity 1.2 source code](http://unity.codeplex.com/releases/view/18855) which contains source for the *Locator* class. I extracted the *Locator* class into my own solution, and after adding a couple of minor dependencies (*Guard.cs*, and the *Properties* folder), fixing up some namespaces, and updating the templates, I was able to successfully generate the data/service layers for my project.

Answer (score 0):

There was same error. My unity version was 2.1.505.2

First downgrade `Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505`

and then upgrade `Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2`

It worked for me.