# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2'

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-assembly

I have verified this is working on local machine but not working on Server machine(Prod).
Also tested adding "Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2" dll in bin folder. but not worked for me.

Error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Following are lib files used in our project:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.dll
```

Is there any solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll not found after installing Enterprise Lib 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302379/microsoft-practices-objectbuilder2-dll-not-found-after-installing-enterprise-lib)

Comment: No, this is different issue. i think this issue is introduce when we migrate .net framework 4.0 to 4.5. is there any dependency..